# Messaging to UI thread

Tags: android, multithreading, messaging, knx

I am developing a serialport application for knx modules in android. I can send and recieve commends to knx modulde.
I want to change ui(for ex. button properties) when a message recieved from serialport. I tried it with handlers but i havent be able to change ui. help me plss.

> @Override     public void OnSerialsData(final byte[] buffer, final int
>   size) { .... }

its my serialport listener function calling insine ReadThread. This thread is starting in differend package from my activity. I want to send a message in this method to main activity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Activity.runOnUiThread()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) to communicate with UI thread. Read more about [Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html), especially about [worker threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#WorkerThreads).

For example within your `OnSerialsData`, you can call

```
mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        mActivity.mButton.setText("message arrived!");
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not an activity. Its a java class that i am using to communicate serial port

Comment: You need to get a handle to modify that activity. see updated answer.

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-123
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
 I got that error when i try to do it

Answer (score 3):

first you have to create a static handler inside your main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

public static Handler myHandler = new Handler(){

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.handleMessage(msg);

        Log.e("Test", msg.getData().getCharSequence("MAINLIST").toString());

    }

};
}
```

then in your socket class:

```
public void OnSerialsData(final byte[] buffer, final int size) {

    Message msg = MainActivity.myHandler.obtainMessage();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putCharSequence("MAINLIST", "IS_OK");
    msg.setData(bundle);
    MainActivity.myHandler.sendMessage(msg);

}
```

but you have to ensure that your handler must be created before you call OnSerialsData method.

I hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

just extending @auselen answer.

Create on your activity the following:

```
public void messageReceived(final String msg){
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
    // Put here your code to update the UI

    }
});
}
```

and then you can call this from any class that have a reference to your activity.
If the class does not have a reference to the activity, then you should pass the reference to it.